# mongodb geospatial query

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I have a mongodb collection structured like this:

```
/* 1 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("551c53f3ecba12e015000045"),
  "nome" : "istituzione1",
  "username" : "username1",
  "email" : "some@email.it",
  "pwd" : "189bbbb00c5f1fb7fba9ad9285f193d1",
  "punti" : [{
      "punto_id" : ObjectId("551c5415ecba12e015000046"),
      "nome" : "ORACLE",
      "loc" : [-122.262168, 37.531595],
      "icona" : 2,
      "youtubelink" : "",
      "immagini" : [{
          "imgid" : ObjectId("551c5d3eecba12e015000084"),
          "contenttype" : "image/jpeg"
        }, {
          "imgid" : ObjectId("551c5d96ecba12e01500008a"),
          "contenttype" : "image/jpeg"
        }]
    }, {
      "punto_id" : ObjectId("551c5420ecba12e015000047"),
      "nome" : "GOOGLE\r\n",
      "loc" : [-122.083983, 37.422969],
      "icona" : 2,
      "youtubelink" : "",
      "immagini" : []
    }, {
      "punto_id" : ObjectId("551c5d74ecba12e015000089"),
      "nome" : "YAHOO",
      "loc" : [-122.025061, 37.428061],
      "icona" : 1,
      "youtubelink" : "",
      "immagini" : [{
          "imgid" : ObjectId("551c5da4ecba12e01500008e"),
          "contenttype" : "image/jpeg"
        }, {
          "imgid" : ObjectId("551c5daaecba12e015000092"),
          "contenttype" : "image/jpeg"
        }, {
          "name" : "Penguins.jpg",
          "imgid" : ObjectId("551c5dfeecba12e015000096"),
          "contenttype" : "image/jpeg"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I created a 2d index on the "loc" array inside "punti" and I'm trying do to a geospatial query like this:

```
db.istituzioni.find({ "punti.loc" : { $geoWithin : { $centerSphere : [ [ -121.931076, 37.364700 ], 14.5 / 6371 ] } } })
```

This query should return only the element of "punti" with the field "nome" set to "YAHOO" (I verified this creating an other collection containig only "loc" and "nome" fields), but it returns the entire collection.
I tried with different km values and discovered that with a value >= 10.9 km it returns the entire collection, while if the value is < 10.9 km the query returns nothing.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries return documents, not elements of arrays in documents. If you want a query to return just an element of `punti`, you should change your document structure or have another collection populated with `punti` elements.

You can also use the $ positional operator in a projection to return the `punti` array just with the first element that matches the query condition:

```
db.istituzioni.find(
    { "punti.loc" : { $geoWithin : { $centerSphere : [ [ -121.931076, 37.364700 ], 14.5 / 6371 ] } } },
    { "punti.$" : 1 }
)
```